# How to use a USB connection in more than one program?

Tags: usbserial

I have an amateur telescope management application which uses two Windows applications, one is a DLL and the other a winforms app, both created using C#

Both these programs communicate with the same AVR  microcontroller via two separate  USB to serial FTDI devices.

The volume of serial traffic is very low  and could easily be managed (with appropriate protocols) over one USB connection rather than the two currently in use.

Is it possible for the two programs to essentially share one USB connection?

If it’s possible, any pointers to resources which would help me to learn how to do it would be much appreciated.

Comment: We need to know more about both of the other two programs to give you any meaningful suggestions.  MY GUESS: 1) both programs probably do the equivalent of `File.Open("myusb.device", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);`, in which case 2) If you tried to run both programs concurrently, one of them would get a "file in use by another process" exception.  Q: What (if anything) have you tried?  What were the results?

Comment: What can you change in your setup? The AVR code? The Windows applications? The DLL?

Comment: What do you actually want to optimize? Free up USB ports on your computer? Reduce the amount of hardware at the expense of more software? Reduce the number of cables between your computer and whatever the device is between computer and telescope?

Comment: If I try to connect to the port (e.g.COM6) from both applications, whichever opens and connects first can use the port, access is denied to the other program.

Comment: In terms of what I can change in my setup, I can change any part. I just don't know what kind of changes to make to allow more than one program to see the data on the port.

Comment: and in answer to what I want to optimise, it's making fewer cable connections which aslo means one less FTDI deice. I hope that overall the application will be less complex.

Comment: I guess one solution would be to modify the DLL so that it deals with all the serial i/o. Then I would need to be able to 'share' the DLL between clients if that's possible.

Comment: Did you do some research how to use a crossbar-like software solution like [com0com](https://com0com.sourceforge.net/), which includes hub4com?

Comment: Thanks for the com0com/ hub4com idea, coincidentally I have been looking at that and I think it would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the options you have are:

**Multiplexing solutions**

Use a single serial connection with a multiplexing protocol. The multiplexing protocol will need to be packet based, and each packet contains a field indicating if it belongs to the communication with the first or second application.

On the Windows side, you have at least three options to implement it:

1. Create an additional process for multiplexing (merging/splitting) the two separate communication streams. This process opens and owns the underlying serial connection. The two applications no longer access the serial connection directly. Instead, they use inter-process communication to talk to the multiplexing process.
2. Make one of the applications the master for the serial connection. It will open and own it. The second application uses inter-process communication to talk to the master application whenever it wants to communicate with the telescope. It will require that the master application runs whenever the second applications runs, possibly in the background only.
3. Create a Windows driver that creates two additional COM ports and handles the multiplexing on the underlying serial connection.

All these options require a considerable investment into software and increase complexity. The third one requires specialized know-how.

**USB solutions**

Instead of communicating over serial connections, use USB instead. Use a microcontroller with USB device capability, and implement either two USB CDC interfaces (which appear as two COM ports on Windows), or two USB interfaces with a custom protocol (and use WinUSB calls to access them).

With two separate USB interfaces, Windows will let two separate applications open the device and communicate with it. And the USB protocol does the multiplexing for you.

**Hardware solution**

Since USB-to-serial converters and USB hubs are inexpensive, a possible approach would be to put the AVR microcontroller, two USB-to-serial converters and a USB hub into a single case. It would make for a nice device connect with a single USB cable (on the PC side). And it wouldn't require any changes to the software.

(*We don't know anything about how your AVR MCU is connected to the telescope. So it's difficult to tell if this is helpful.*)

Comment: Thanks very much for this comprehensive reply. The hardware solution is a very nice idea and involves very litle modification to my hardware.